# Difference between if and elif

Tags: python

I started solving the LeetCode problem. But I stuck on easy problem. Yess. But I found the solution. And I mistoken the elif and if statements. Who can explain me differences between if and elif in this code:

```
ret = []
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
                ret.append('FizzBuzz')
            if i % 3 == 0:
                ret.append('Fizz')
            if i % 5 == 0:
                ret.append('Buzz')
            else:
                ret.append(str(i))
        return ret
```

If I change the if to elif. Problem will be solved.

If you didn't understand my problem you can see the description of problem.

Here's the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz/description/)

**solution only with if statements:**

input: n = 3

output: ["1","2","Fizz","3"]

expected: ["1","2","Fizz"]

Solution when I change some if s to elif:

output:  ["1","2","Fizz"]

expected: ["1","2","Fizz"]

Comment: `elif` will not be executed when then corresponding `if` was already met. Consecutive `if`s will all just be expected regardless of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Python will evaluate all three if statements to determine if they are true. Once a condition in the if elif else statement is true, Python stop evaluating the other conditions.
So for 15, you will get three results to your list instead one correct answer:

```
In [15]: n = 15

In [16]: if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
    ...:     ret.append('FizzBuzz')
    ...: if i % 3 == 0:
    ...:     ret.append('Fizz')
    ...: if i % 5 == 0:
    ...:     ret.append('Buzz')
    ...: else:
    ...:     ret.append(str(i))
    ...:

In [17]: ret
Out[17]: ['FizzBuzz', 'Fizz', 'Buzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider every if block as an independent block, so when you assign 3 then in two loop it executed the else part of the last if block, in third iteration it executed the the first if block but again it has to execute all remaining two other if block since every if block is independent from each other and thus it it executed the last if block and found the else part which is again satisfied the condition.

so, coming to your question, every if block is independent to each other and get executed each time iteration occur but in elif it becomes a single block that will only execute for once in every iteration.